# How to transfer wordpress site from GoDaddy to 1and1 hosting

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to transfer a GoDaddy Wordpress site to 1and1 hosting and I'm getting these errors

> Warning: parse_ini_file(): Filename cannot be empty! in /homepages/10/d600106068/htdocs/brandonstaging/wp-content/mu-plugins/gd-system-plugin/includes/class-configs.php on line 158
>
> Warning: parse_ini_file(): Filename cannot be empty! in /homepages/10/d600106068/htdocs/brandonstaging/wp-content/mu-plugins/gd-system-plugin/includes/class-configs.php on line 158
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/10/d600106068/htdocs/brandonstaging/wp-content/mu-plugins/gd-system-plugin/includes/class-configs.php:158) in /homepages/10/d600106068/htdocs/brandonstaging/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1174

I changed the site_url to be my staging site but that didn't help at all. Anyone know how to resolve?

Comment: Is this a WPMU installation?

Comment: As the error message suggests, look at line 158 of the "class-configs.php" file in the "/homepages/10/d600106068/htdocs/brandonstaging/wp-content/mu-plugins/gd-system-plugin/includes" directory.  What did you find there?  Update your question with this useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this issue is coming from the plugin stored at `/wp-content/mu-plugins/gd-system-plugin`, if I am not mistaken this is a GoDaddy system plugin. Assuming this is the case, your issue would be resolved by deleting the `gd-system-plugin` folder.

Comment: yes that seemed to be the problem. We ended up just remaking the site as that did not entirely solve the issue 8( note to self, never transfer a site from godaddy hosting to another host...

Comment: For a client site the plugin had also already been removed from `mu-plugins` as well as the object caching file `object-cache.php` in `wp-content`. Still GoDaddy Managed WordPress remained (loaded in admin bar) and so connected to GoDaddy post migration to DreamPress. Looking into a way to deal with properly now.